# How do i return arrays to compute total and find the largest value?

Tags: java, arrays, return

I am trying to return the sum of all the values in the the array while also trying to return the largest value to the main method, however, the program states that I have an error at return total and at return number. The error states, "Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to int[]."

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    int myArray[] = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i <= myArray.length-1; i++ ) {
        System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
        int nums = number.nextInt();
        myArray[i] = nums;
   }
   int [] sum = computeTotal(myArray);
   System.out.println("The numbers total up to: "+sum);
   int [] largest = getLargest(myArray);
   System.out.println("The largest number is: "+largest);
}

public static int[] computeTotal(int myArray[]) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int z : myArray){
        total += z;
    }
    return total;
}
public static int[] getLargest(int myArray[]) {
    int number = myArray[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if(myArray[i] > number) {
            number = myArray[i]; 
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes error messages can be confusing. Not in this case. `return number` is trying to return an int, but the method return type is `int[]`

Comment: Wow...what an obvious gaffe on my part. Anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods `computeTotal` and `getLargest`should be changed the return types to int. Please refer this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
        int myArray[] = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i <= myArray.length-1; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
            int nums = number.nextInt();
            myArray[i] = nums;
       }
       int sum = computeTotal(myArray);
       System.out.println("The numbers total up to: "+sum);
       int largest = getLargest(myArray);
       System.out.println("The largest number is: "+largest);
    }

    public static int computeTotal(int myArray[]) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int z : myArray){
            total += z;
        }
        return total;
    }
    public static int getLargest(int myArray[]) {
        int number = myArray[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if(myArray[i] > number) {
                number = myArray[i]; 
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in java8 there're easier way to get the max and sum.

```
int sum = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2, 3}).sum();            //6 
int max = Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,3, 2}).max().getAsInt(); //3
```